# Ubuntu gearman setup with mod-gearman-tools

Tags: php, ubuntu, gearman

I am trying to install gearman on ubuntu and would like to install the mod-gearman-tools so that I will be able to use gearman_top to check for my workers. So far I have managed to get gearman working and installed gearmanManager for deamon workers.

I would like to run gearman_top to check the number of workers I have (I have two type) as I suspect only one of them are registered. When I run gearman_top I get this error message:

> "gearman_top: error while loading shared libraries: libgearman.so.6:
>   cannot open shared object file: Error 40"

this is the process I have followed to setup:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:gearman-developers
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libgearman6 libgearman-dev gearman-job-server

sudo pecl install gearman

echo "extension=gearman.so" | sudo tee /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
echo "extension=gearman.so" | sudo tee /etc/php5/cli/php.ini

sudo apt-get install gearman-tools mod-gearman-tools

sudo service apache2 restart #restart apache

git clone https://github.com/brianlmoon/GearmanManager.git /var/gearman/GearmanManager
/var/gearman/GearmanManager/install/install.sh
```

thanks in advance,
any help appreciated guys!